# Apache reverse proxy, HTML form submission

Tags: forms, apache, proxy, submit, reverse

I have set up an Apache reverse proxy on server A that maps address: address1.com/app to ipaddress/app2.
in the target page there's a login form, which uses a post method and calling a php file and it works fine.
But same time there's another sign up form that the submit button is linked to the "#" and is using java script for processing it, the problem starts when I click the submit button and it calls: address1.com/app1/app1 and so tries to open ipaddress.com/app2/app1 which doesn't exist.
I think maybe I need to use rewrite mode for solving it but after some works I couldn't.
I appreciate your kind help if you can.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is solved. and just to help other people save their time if they get to this post, this is the best you can do!
Using apache reverse proxy gave me much headache and days os wasting time and each time different errors! Then I realized that the Plesk 11.5 has Nginx integrated and it's as easy as editing a conf file of the host  you want to use the reverse proxy on it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully visualize your problem but based on what you said

> another sign up form that the submit button is linked to the "#" and
>   is using java script for processing it,

This could be solved by using a full URL for the javascript form Submit. In the "target=" form field (if javascript is pulling POST URL from there) change to a full URL and see if that helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Actually there's a signup link and then a signup page.  This is the code for the signup button: <a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.myForm.submit();" class="cssbutton_big"> . I'll try your sulution.

Comment: As probably there are more forms in the other pages on the private server, I hope I can find a way to solve this from the reverse proxy side.